# Why invoking a getter method cannot be printed to screen directly?

Tags: java, methods, getter

I was doing a very basic java course and it is introducing getter methods. However, there is something which I don't understand.

```
class Person {

    String name;
    int age;

void speak() {
    System.out.println("My name is : " + name);
}

int calculateYearsToRetirement() { 
    int yearsLeft = 65 - age;

    return yearsLeft;
}

int getAge() {
    return age;
}

String getName() {
    return name;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Person person1 = new Person();

    person1.name = "Joe";
    person1.age = 25;

    person1.speak();

    int years = person1.calculateYearsToRetirement();
    System.out.println("Years till retirement : " + years);


    //System.out.println(person1.getAge());
    //System.out.println(person1.getName());

    int age = person1.getAge();
    String name = person1.getName();

    System.out.println("Age is : " + age);
    System.out.println("Name is : " + name);

    }
}
```

Please have a look at my code comments.
I tried that and it has no problem printing to screen at all.
But when I tried:

```
System.out.println("person1.calculateYearsToRetirement");
```

it doesn't work.

However, I was told that I have assign an `int` variable `years` to `person1.calculateYearsToRetirement` then print the variable to screen.

Can you guys explain to me why is this so?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know what a `String` is?

Comment: If you merge the two lines then you get this: `System.out.println("Years till retirement : " + person1.calculateYearsToRetirement());`, the same for age and name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling any function (or getter, which is a function).

Double-quotation marks create `String` objects in Java.

This means that this part:

```
System.out.println("person1.calculateYearsToRetirement");
```

Prints the string `"person1.calculateYearsToRetirement"`, which was explicitly constructed by the quotation marks.

What you meant was probably:

```
System.out.println(person1.calculateYearsToRetirement());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to print the value returned by the method call, you have to remove the speech marks and append parentheses.

```
System.out.println(person1.calculateYearsToRetirement());
```

Using speech marks will print the `String` rather than the result of the method call. I suggest that you read some basic Java tutorials in order to learn about the language.